# Jquery plugin menu - bind or live

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning how to do my own Jquery plugin and I'm starting with some basic stuff.

You can see my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/denislexic/8YBM6/8/

**This needs to be binded**, ie, some of the time the elements will be AJAX loaded, so the plugin still needs to work. (in the fiddle I added a button that copies the content, so I could test it out, but no luck...)

I usually just do live or on. I'm trying to learn and understand.

Thanks

Comment: @Marc - I need the plugin to be live/on, so when some new content is loaded (which will be very frequently) I need the menu to still show up...thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aR8RQ/1/

Changes I made include:

I'm using event delegation for the 'avatars' element(s). Previously the events were binded using .each() which would have only binded the events on the initial call for the plugin.

I'm using .data() to store the state of the menu (whether it's open or close) and added some event bindings on the document to handle closing the menu.

I added comments to hopefully help you out! I think this does everything you originally asked for (for instance: hiding the menu if you click on anything other than that). There's still some work you can do (for instance, when you "duplicate" you can handle the "close" method for your menus more gracefully!)

Hopefully this helps! :)

Comment: woow, amazing.  That s a huge change. Thanks. I'm still going through it to understand.

Comment: It s awesome, I still don t understand everything, but getting closer!  Last quick question, there should only be one pop up open at a time. How can I hide the others if a new one is going to open?  Thanks a million!